# How can I see 2 Series over my chart on the same graph when values are different (very high and very low)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graph, charts

I define 2 Series (I am using `Telerik`) that represent my `Network Traffic rate` (`MBit/sec` and `Packet/sec`):

```
AreaSeries series;
AreaSeries series2;

series = new AreaSeries();
radChartView1.Series.Add(series);
series.BorderColor = Color.SteelBlue;
series.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, Color.SkyBlue);
series.BorderWidth = 1;
series.HorizontalAxis.ShowLabels = false;
series.VerticalAxis.ShowLabels = false;

series2 = new AreaSeries();
radChartView1.Series.Add(series2);
series2.BorderColor = Color.Gray;
series2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, Color.Gray);
series2.BorderWidth = 1;
series2.HorizontalAxis.ShowLabels = false;
series2.VerticalAxis.ShowLabels = false;
```

My chart received the real time data via Timer:

```
private void timerStatistics_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (series.DataPoints.Count > 40)
            series.DataPoints.RemoveAt(0);
        series.DataPoints.Add(new Telerik.Charting.CategoricalDataPoint(AdapterStatistics.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001));

        if (series2.DataPoints.Count > 40)
            series2.DataPoints.RemoveAt(0);
        series2.DataPoints.Add(new Telerik.Charting.CategoricalDataPoint(AdapterStatistics.PacketsPerSecond));

    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

And my problem is that because my 2 values are very different i only can see one of my Series (usually `Packet/sec`) because for example `MBit/sec` get the value 1.4 and `Packet/sec` get the value 200 so from my chart i can see the biggest value, the lowest value is so small that it cannot be seen (see my screenshot inside the red rectangle a very small blue line... ):

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it applies to `Telerik` controls, but in the regular chart control, you can have 2 x-axes and 2 y-axes, and assign different series to use different axes. Thus, you could do something like:

```
series.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
series2.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
Axis yaxis1 = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
Axis yaxis2 = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2;
yaxis1.Maximum = 1e6;
yaxis2.Maximum = 1e3;
```

Looks like it's very similar using `Telerik` controls, taken straight from the Telerik website (http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/chartview-axes-multiple-axes.html):

```
LinearAxis verticalAxis1 = new LinearAxis();
verticalAxis1.AxisType = AxisType.Second;
LinearAxis verticalAxis2 = new LinearAxis();
verticalAxis2.AxisType = AxisType.Second;
verticalAxis2.HorizontalLocation = AxisHorizontalLocation.Right;

series.HorizontalAxis = horizontalAxis;
series.VerticalAxis = verticalAxis1;


series2.HorizontalAxis = horizontalAxis;
series2.VerticalAxis = verticalAxis2;
```

Comment: In this case still there is a big different between the 2 lines so one of them almost not visible

Comment: That's exactly what multiple axes are for, so I don't know why it wouldn't work. Can you post your updated code showing my implementation, and an updated screenshot?